# GWT - XSS prevention and rendering safe/simple html

Tags: java, html, gwt, xss

I would like to know what are the best ways to prevent XSS in a GWT app while still providing a way for users to edit and view custom html (for ex.  a rich text editor).

Specifically, if a user tries to store an evil hidden code in a public entity that is meant to be viewed as html by other users, I would like to make sure that the evil html is not executed.

Example:

```
<img src=a onerror="alert('evil');">
<br>
<b>test1</b>
<font>test2</font>
```

In this code, I would like to allow the `<br>`, `<b>`, `<font>` tags and even  `<img>`, but I want to strip the javascript. I tried testing the SafeHtml utility classes but: SafeHtmlBuilder and SafeHtmlUtils are escaping all the tags (so this would be good for a form with first name, last name, but not good when rendering the text from a rich text editor right?) and SimpleHtmlSanitizer has only very few allowed tags.

My question is, is there a way to achieve this in GWT (protecting the "good" users from the "bad" when rendering a html) or it is a must that the text processing should be done on server-side ?

Comment: I suggest googling "gwt xss" and reading the first two documents.

Answer (score 1):

This is what [`HtmlSanitizer`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/safehtml/shared/HtmlSanitizer.html) is for. The `SimpleHtmlSanitizer` might be a bit too simple for your use case but can serve as a good basis to build your own.

Comment: So basically, if I want to allow for ex. <img> tags, but not javascript callbacks like "onerror", I should write the code that strips the html I don't need, in the "sanitize" method?